# Show an Array of 10 Ints in a label

Tags: arrays, swift, label, multiplication

I'm trying to build a basic multiplication app that will show your 1 times tables up to 10 times tables depending which number you type into the text field.

When I run my code, my label only produces 1 line which is the result of the last multiplication calculated. For example 10 times 8 is 80, the other 9 do not get added, also after this my full array displays showing the correct answer to the tables. Here is my code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var numberTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var tablesLabel: UILabel!

    var tablesArray = [Int]()

    var number = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func tablesButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        if numberTextField.text == "" {
            print("Sorry you must enter a number between 1 and 10")
        } else {
            tablesArray = []
            tablesLabel.text = ""
            multiplyBy(number: Int(numberTextField.text!)!)
            numberTextField.text = ""
        }
    }
    func multiplyBy(number: Int) {

        for index in 1...10 {
           tablesArray.append(index * number)
            print(tablesArray)
            tablesLabel.text = ("\(index) times \(number) is \(tablesArray)")
        }
        tablesLabel.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: because it's looping till last one .. you should save those in an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
tablesLabel.text = ("\(index) times \(number) is \(tablesArray)")
```

to

```
tablesLabel.text = ("\(tablesLabel.text ?? "") \(index) times \(number) is \(tablesArray)")
```

You overwrite the label's text every time. This does not overwrite the label's text and adds the new text to it.